# MUI DataGrid: How to use another column for display than the column grouped on

Tags: material-ui, grouping

I am using the row grouping feature of x-data-grid-premium.

To be sure that I group on what uniquely identifies a group I need to group another column that the column value I want to display.

Example: I want the data-grid to group on an "id column", but display a "name column", to prevent rows with same name (but different ids) being grouped together. I have tried using the groupingValueGetter on the column def, but also changes the display value.

Maybe what I ask for is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the id to group the rows and change the displayed value by using the `valueGetter` property of the `groupingColDef` prop:

```
<DataGrid 
  {...props}
  groupingColDef: {
    valueGetter(params) {
      return params.row.name;
    },
  }
/>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, can you provide an example?